# Give script time to execute, if exceeded, stop it

Tags: shell, timeout

Is this possible, to give max time in seconds to script for execution?

for example, i have script, that pings some network. Usually, it takes about 10 seconds, but if execution takes more than 10 seconds, just kill it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `timeout` command, e.g. `time 10s myscript`.

```
man timeout
TIMEOUT(1)                       User Commands                      TIMEOUT(1)

NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit
```